Как убрать ошибку в аддоне для мода на Java
Хотел попробовать написать свой первый аддон, а именно аддон для мода HarvestCraft в майнкрафте, для версии 1.12.2. Установил вроде бы всё, OpenJDK, MDK, Gradle, настроил среду для разработки в IntelliJ Idea, короче, всё что надо, но столкнулся с ошибкой. Когда я запускаю клиент через командную строку командой:
> ./gradlew runClient

То вылезает вот такая ошибка
14:53:32.619 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Execution failed for task ':runClient'.
14:53:32.619 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] > Process 'command 'C:\Users\Uuuser\OneDrive\╨рсюўшщ ёЄюы\java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.392-1.b08.redhat.windows.x86_64\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value -1
14:53:32.619 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
14:53:32.619 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Try:
14:53:32.619 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.  Run with --scan to get full insights.
14:53:32.620 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
14:53:32.620 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
14:53:32.620 [WARN] [org.gradle.internal.featurelifecycle.LoggingDeprecatedFeatureHandler]
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 5.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/4.9/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
14:53:32.621 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildResultLogger]
14:53:32.621 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildResultLogger] BUILD FAILED in 26s

Пожалуйста, помогите с решением этой ошибки, и расскажите пожалуйста в чем причина этой фигни! Заранее огромное спасибо!

Вы лучше места не нашли, чтобы установить OpenJDK, чем "C:\Users\Uuuser\OneDrive\╨рсюўшщ ёЄюы"?

Ахах, сейчас попробую перенести с этого ╨рсюўшщ ёЄюы куда-то в C:\

Всё равно также, эта же ошибка, только путь уже другой
